# What if we had approx "read times" displayed?

Tags: feature-request, design

I was reading thru [Medium's blog](https://blog.medium.com/read-time-and-you-bc2048ab620c) where they explain how and why they implemented the "read time", and some claim, based on science and anecdotes that this would [increase engagement](https://marketingland.com/estimated-reading-times-increase-engagement-79830).

> Read time is based on the average reading speed of an adult (roughly 275 WPM). We take the total word count of a post and translate it into minutes. Then, we add 12 seconds for each inline image. Boom, read time.
>   <sub>[Medium's Blog "3 min read"](https://blog.medium.com/read-time-and-you-bc2048ab620c)</sub>

> If a page is heavy on visuals, as in the case of infographics and slideshows, then the estimated reading time isn’t going to be accurate. Product and landing pages shouldn’t distract a visitor from their purpose, which is to sell — no matter how long that takes. And if your articles or blog posts never run more than a couple hundred words, tops, do you really want “1 minute” “1 minute” “1 minute” “1 minute” “1 minute” at the top of all of them?
>   
>   <sub>Arienne Holland's op-ed on [Marketing Land](https://marketingland.com/estimated-reading-times-increase-engagement-79830)</sub>

We could have a small indicator on **long** posts (not every post) showing estimated read times like "2 min read", etc.

What if SE implemented this feature as well? Especially for those non-programming sites. What are your thoughts? Good idea or bad?

---

Note: The [userscript by rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303656/309993) works like a charm. See accepted answer below. It displays only when the text takes more than 1 min to read.

Comment: If not implemented by SE, then a user script can do this.

Comment: @rene I see. And is there one you know of?

Comment: No, but I didn't check on https://stackapps.com/ ... it shouldn't be too hard though. It is pretty clear where the post text is in an SE html page.

Comment: @rene I already checked but didn't find any on stackapps. Maybe I'm not knowing how to actually look for it.

Comment: this should get anyone started: `$('.post-text').each(function() { var l = this.textContent.split(' ').length; $(this).prepend($('<span>').text('reading time:' + Math.round(l/275,1) + ' minute(s)'))});` the exact word count and compensating for images needs a better implementation.

Comment: @rene thanks. Unfortunately, I have no coding knowledge. If in case you (or others) happen to write a full script, I may be able to add that thru tampermonkey.

Comment: As you wish, TamperMonkey script is done now ...

Comment: @rene thanks. But on clicking the direct link, I'm taken to a chrome tab, all text, but tampermonkey won't pick it up. Something wrong on my system?

Comment: sorry, I forgot that the js file needs to be following a naming convention, now fixed.

Comment: @rene Installed. Nice. Can we shorten it to "2 min read" as seen on Medium?

Comment: done that as well, re-install to get version 0.2

Comment: According to your calculations, your question should take 44 seconds to read. I timed myself and it took 41 seconds. Quite accurate.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Not my calculations.

Comment: On one hand, there's some sites... and well users where I see value in seeing time to read. Not really sure about it for stuff like SO and SU

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Which is why it doesn't have to be done for _all_ stacks or posts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Until this gets implemented use the following user script:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Add reading time
// @namespace   https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene
// @version      0.3
// @description  adds reading time to each question and answer
// @author       rene
// @match        https://*.stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @match        https://*.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @match        https://*.superuser.com/questions/*
// @match        https://*.serverfault.com/questions/*
// @match        https://*.askubuntu.com/questions/*
// @match        https://*.stackapps.com/questions/*
// @match        https://*.mathoverflow.net/questions/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function($) {
    'use strict';

    function numberOfWords(text) {
        var wordsregex = /\b(\w+)\b/g,
            match,
            tot = 0;
        while ((match = wordsregex.exec(text)) !== null) {
            // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches, as found on https://regex101.com/r/byXy4H/1/
            if (match.index === wordsregex.lastIndex) {
                regex.lastIndex++;
            }
            tot++;
        }
        // console.log('words: ' + tot);
        return tot;
    }

    function numberOfImages($post) {
        var tagCount = 0;
        ['img', 'svg'].forEach(function(elem) {
            tagCount += $post.find(elem).length;
        });
        // console.log('images: ' + tagCount);
        return tagCount;
    }

    function readingTimeInMinutes(wordCount, imageCount) {
        // words is 275 per minute, 15 seconds per image
        const WPM = 275;
        const SecondsPerImage = 15;
        var wordMinutes = ((wordCount || 0) / WPM),
            imageMinutes = ((imageCount || 0) * SecondsPerImage) / 60;

        // add and ceil()
        return Math.ceil(wordMinutes + imageMinutes);
    }

    $('.post-text').each(function () {
        var words = numberOfWords(this.textContent);
        var images = numberOfImages($(this));
        var minutes = readingTimeInMinutes(words, images);
        // giant S
        var minutelabel = minutes === 1 ? "minute": "minutes";
        if (minutes > 1) {
            $(this)
                .prepend(
                $('<span>')
                .text(minutes + ' min read')
                .prop('title', minutes + ' ' + minutelabel +' reading time for ' + words + ' words and ' + images + ' images')
                .addClass('label-key')
            );
        } else {
            console.log('no reading time shown for ' + minutes + ' ' + minutelabel +' reading time for ' + words + ' words and ' + images + ' images');
        }
    });
})($);
```

Find its source on GitHub [here](https://github.com/rschrieken/SmallButHandy/blob/master/readingtime.user.js) or [install](https://github.com/rschrieken/SmallButHandy/raw/master/readingtime.user.js) directly.

Tested with TamperMonkey on Chrome.

When it works and the reading time is over a minute this is what you'll get:

[image: FAQ with time and tooltip]

(for exposure I posted on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/7676/reading-time-for-each-post) as well.)

Comment: Nice. It shows. SE probably won't implement it anytime soon. And I'd be downvoted to hell and back for this. But you have been very helpful. :)

Comment: Perhaps updating screenshot would be nice. The changed wording, and the "1 min" text now being hidden and all. Perhaps a screenshot of the FAQs; it shows "7 min". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/309993

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will be useful, because Stack Exchange sites are not meant to be tutorials.

They are Q&A sites, with focused answers on specific questions. The answers are not blog posts.

If answer is very long, it usually means the author included parts which are not totally relevant to the question, or elaborated a lot on some details. Etiher way, the occasional visitor will likely not need to read everything, just the relevant parts for their own case.

Comment: I understand that. I have for the moment found rene's script very useful. It's pretty basic now. Hopefully it can be modified later to add extra conditions and stuff :)